# Remove all characters after "-"

Tags: php, regex

I thought this would work but it appears to be only removing the - and the whitespace after it.

```
$itemList[] = preg_replace('/-(.*?)/i', "", $temp['item']);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
$itemList[] = preg_replace('/-(.*)$/i', "", $temp['item']);
```

The $ symbol matches the end of the input, so forces the .* to grab to the end.

Adding a ? after the * makes it un-greedy, meaning it will grab the minimum possible, not the maximum possible, so in this case it is exactly what you don't want.

Comment: Actually, removing the `?` should be enough. `.*` will be greedy and match as much as it can. Works either way, though.

Answer (score 2):

Why were you using non-greedy `*?` ?

```
$itemList[] = preg_replace('/-.*/i', "", $temp['item']);
```

Also, the capturing parens were unnecessary.